# Object property returns undefined using observable .map

Tags: typescript, angular5

Angular 5 Type Script.

I'm having an issue where the property of an Dog[] is not accessible when using the map feature. My goal is to get a json response, parse the IDs and create several new requests with that response. I've written two http services that call two different endpoint.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Dog } from '../dog'
import { DogService } from '../dog.service'
import { DogpagesService } from '../dogpages.service'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switch';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-girls',
  templateUrl: './girls.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./girls.component.css']
})
export class GirlsComponent implements OnInit {
  dogs: Observable<Dog[]>;

  constructor(
    private dogService: DogService,
    private dogpagesService: DogpagesService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dogpagesService.getPage('girls')
      .map(res =>
        res.map((val) => {
          console.log(val)
          return val.DogsId
        }))
      .subscribe(obsNumbers => obsNumbers
        .map(num => this.dogService
          .getDog(num)
          .subscribe(dog => console.log(dog)
          )));
  }

}
```

The following gets logged to the console.

```
{dogsId: 159, pageName: "Girls", sortId: 2}
{dogsId: 11, pageName: "Girls", sortId: 1}

GET https://localhost:44342/api/dogs/undefined 400
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44342/api/dogs/undefined", ok: false, …}
```

Why is dogsID available during console.log(val), but NOT when I subscribe to it later?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `val.dogsId` with a lowercase `d`.

Comment: That was it. I defined my class with upper case. Why would it expect differently.export class Pages {
    DogsId: number
    PageName: string
    SortId: number
}

Comment: What is actually creating the `Pages` object?  If you are just doing `JSON.parse` of data from some server and assigning it to a `Pages` object, TypeScript can't check whether the data matches your class.

Comment: return this.http.get<Pages[]>(url)

Comment: Right, then if the server returns a lowercase `d`, that is what you will get regardless of what the `Pages` class says.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!